# Highcharts 8 upgrade : No exported member for Highcharts.DataPoint

Tags: highcharts

I'm upgrading highcharts from 6.2 to 8.2.2 in an angular/typescript project but a lot of classes doesn't exists anymore.

I can't find any upgrade guide listing what was refactored and how.

For instance I can't find what is the new name for `Highcharts.DataPoint`.

Someone know?

Comment: Have you already seen the docs? https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/highcharts-typescript-declarations and https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/

Comment: Excellent, didn't saw that. Thanks. Unfortunately, I would also need the one from 6.x to 7.x cause I'm in 6.20 right now. It seems the site only propose the latest version documentation.

Comment: I am afraid that this type of document doesn't exist. The version before the 7 was a beta version: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-declarations-beta/. After updating to the current one you should remove the previous version because the new pack includes all TS declaration.

Comment: Ok thanks. Did it but without migration guide, was quite tedious and difficult. Something that would help a lot when doing this would be to mention typescript types in the online doc.